# Typescript: Function overloading

Tags: typescript

What would be the easiest way to achieve / implement such a function overload  in TypeScript?

```
function Foo(
    param1: number,
    param2: string,
    param3: string,
    param4: () => void,
    param5: (xyz: string) => void): void { .... }

function Foo(
    param6: number,
    param3: string,
    param4: () => void,
    param5: (xyz: string) => void): void { .... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's covered in [Overloads section of the Functions docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), but in your case it can be like this:

```
function Foo(
    param1: number,
    param2: string,
    param3: string,
    param4: () => void,
    param5: (xyz: string) => void): void; 
function Foo(
    param6: number,
    param3: string,
    param4: () => void,
    param5: (xyz: string) => void): void;

function Foo(...args: any[]): void {
    if (args.length === 5) {
        // 1st signature
    } else if (args.length === 4) {
        // 2nd signature
    } else {
        // error: unknown signature
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20Foo(%0D%0A%09param1%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%09param2%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09param3%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09param4%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A%09param5%3A%20(xyz%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20void%3B%20%0D%0Afunction%20Foo(%0D%0A%09param6%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%09param3%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09param4%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A%09param5%3A%20(xyz%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Foo(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(args.length%20%3D%3D%3D%205)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20first%20signature%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20if%20(args.length%20%3D%3D%3D%204)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20first%20signature%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20error%3A%20unknown%20signature%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))